# Unable to download xml file when running as localsystem

Tags: xml, jscript, wsh

The following MS Jscript file it works fine and returns the XML file when I run the script as admin on windows 7. When I run it as LocalSystem, it returns nothing on some PCs.   Looking at the packets Using wireshark, it seems that the local PC is issuing a FIN packet which is stopping the network communication when the script is run using LocalSystem. I would appreciate any pointers.

```
    var filePath = "https://someurlhere";
    WScript.Echo("Reading XML file: " + filePath);

    var xsl = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0");
    xsl.async = false;
    xsl.validateOnParse = false;

    xsl.load(filePath);
    WScript.Echo("XSLT: " + xsl.xml);
```

Comment: "Local" system probably says it all. a local service/process has no business dealing with the network, so it's probably the windows firewall disallowing the connection attempt

Comment: That is not the case. I have created a vbs that is able to download the XML files even when run as LocalSystem:

Comment: I'd guess that `xmlObj.load()` loads from the local filesystem, not from HTTP.  I could be mistaken, but you might have better luck using the `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` COM object.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your MS Jscript file as admin on window 7 then check result . it might be UAC stopping execute the MS Jscript.